# Color filter is causing an error

Tags: vba, excel

This part of the macro (which is the first step) is causing a

> run-time error 9 (sub-script out of range)

on first try but continues normally when I press debug and F8 again and I can't figure out why.

Note on possible reason: when this part of the macro is enabled, another column is already filtered.

```
   ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB _
    (146, 208, 80), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```

Comment: Instead of using `ActiveSheet` specify the sheet by its name like `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. Excel probably assumes the wrong sheet here and that doesn't have a listobject `"Table1"` on it.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense